# Having trouble subtracting variables while using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery and javascript as a whole. I was having trouble while subtracting different variables while using `.click` jQuery. I'm trying to have the value of nmeHealth to be lowered by the variable adjustdmg.

Variables

```
var defdamage = 20;
var strength = 1;
var adjustdmg = strength + defdamage - 1;
var nmeHealth = 100;
```

Function

```
$("#enemy").click(function() {
  if (nmeHealth >= 0) {
    $("#enemyHealth").html(nmeHealth);
    var nmeHealth = nmeHealth - adjustdmg;
  }
})
```

Comment: For clarification, jQuery is not a language; it's a JavaScript library. Can you create a fiddle for your problem?

Comment: parseInt method for converting string to integer i think it will help

Comment: Where is `defdamage` is defined?

Comment: Forgot to include, added now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var nmeHealth` is the problem because it means you're instantiating a new variable (and it belongs to the function scope) instead of modifying the old one. The line:

```
var nmeHealth = nmeHealth - adjustdmg;
```

should be:

```
nmeHealth = nmeHealth - adjustdmg;
```

or shortly:

```
nmeHealth -= adjustdmg;
```

---

Also, if you want to show the current enemy health, and not lag one cycle behind, change the order of the lines as well. I'm talking about this code here:

```
$("#enemyHealth").html(nmeHealth);
var nmeHealth = nmeHealth - adjustdmg;
```

Final version:

```
nmeHealth -= adjustdmg;
$("#enemyHealth").html(nmeHealth);
```

Comment: @Sumtinlazy if this fixed the problem pls tick the check mark to confirm that this question has an accepted answere